# Angularjs route executes twice with particular querystring

Tags: angularjs, query-string, angularjs-routing

I'm developing a SPA AngularJs application, that has to deal with some particular legacy URL's.

I am using the basic $routeProvider that works fine, with one exception: when i invoke a special url like

**host:port/app/index.html#/products?features=contracttype=loyalty&sn=value&filter=2351&20**

the controller gets invoked twice:

1. the first time with the right querystring : **features=contracttype=loyalty&sn=value&filter=2351&20**
2. the second time, the querystring is modified:
   **features=contracttype&sn=value&filter=2351**

I've put debug code in the $routeProvider.config function, and the

```
.when('/products',
{
    controller: 'ProdCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/prod.html'
})
```

gets invoked twice, but only when i have this special type of url.

Everything else works fine when I have a regular qs, like ?param1=value2&param2=value2...

My question is what can I do to get the querystring **unmodified** , and why does the controller get initialized twice ?

I have to emntion I cannot change the querystring ( due to legacy issues ) , all I can do is to pass it along to a backend app.

Answer (score 0):

U have two equal signs following each other, maybe & between?

Comment: I cannot change the URL, its legacy, even if it's this 'weird'. All I want to do is get the whole string, and pass it along to the backEnd ( which is also legacy ) who knows how deal with it, as weird as it is.

Comment: what do you mean by legacy?

Comment: I recommend updating the production module then.  I have never seen that kind of convention before; it will only cause you problems in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query string is incorrect, it cannot be a=b=c, so the router tries to correct it as it thinks best.

Comment: I know the URL it's not correct, but I cannot change it, it's legacy. All I want  to do is get the whole string, and pass it along to the backEnd ( which is also legacy ) who knows how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to achieve that is encoding your url, because with two equals it is invalid.

```
var newUrl = encodeURIComponent("...?features=contracttype=loyalty&...");
```